# Writing to dataframe in double for loop

Tags: r

I have a nested list (`FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]`) in which seperate columns hold values of a matrix (for each x and nested y). Now I want to make the matrices by writing to dataframes.

However, I don't succeed in giving the matrices the correct name in a double for loop. At the moment, I only succeeded in making matrices with information about "x" but not with information about "y". Please help me out or suggest another method to do this.

```
for (x in 1:36){
    for (y in 1:5){
        cells <- c(0,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A12,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A13,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A14,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A21,0,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A23,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A24,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A31,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A32,
                   0,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A34,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A41,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A42,
                   FCdat.pp.con[[x]][[y]]$A43,
                   0)
        rnames <- c("ALG1","ALG2","ALG3","ALG4")
        cnames <- c("ALG1","ALG2","ALG3","ALG4")
        Ind.matr <- t(matrix(cells, nrow=4, ncol = 4))
        dimnames(Ind.matr)=list(rnames, cnames)
        assign(paste0("Indmatr", x), Ind.matr)

    }
}
```

Comment: does the lowest level of the list contain the row (or col) vectors of the desired matrices? This is a little difficult to understand.

Comment: The highest level [[x]] contains information about the subjects (n = 36), whereas the lowest level [[y]] indicates which content (n = 5) is relevant. Next, for each [[x]] and [[y]] I calculated each cell of a matrix. Because I didn't know better, I pasted these matrix values as separate columns to the list.(so 12 columns extra). Now I want to make matrices which I can access with an [[x]] and [[y]] value. I hope this is more clear? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the loop begins: `result <- lapply(1:36, function(.)vector("list",5))`

Then replace `assign(paste0("Indmatr", x), Ind.matr)` with `result[[x]][[y]] <- Ind.matr`.